# Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of non-decreasing fcns. If $\int_X f_1^- d\mu <\infty$ then show $\lim_k \int_X f_k d\mu = \int_X \lim_k f_k d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I need your help to understand and analyse the following problem:

Q: Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of non-decreasing measurable function on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $\mu$ be a positive measure. If $\int_X f_1^- d\mu <\infty$ then show $\lim_k \int_X f_k d\mu =  \int_X  \lim_k f_k d\mu$.

Is $f^-$ here the second part of $f_k = f_k^+ -f_k^-$? And how we can think about this problem? How we can use this fact? Do we have to use Fatou's Lemma or Monotone Convergence Theorem? But the sequence may or may not have a limit (nothing mentioned about it's limit), so probably we may use Fatou's, since it does not require limit to exist.

Or do you think $-$ on $f_1$ is a typo? It might be $f_1'$ or $f_1$. If so, then why?

Any hints or possible solutions?

Comment: Looks like a typo somewhere.  Try $f_k(x)=1/k$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_k(x)dx = \infty$ for all $k > 0$, but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f_k(x)=0$.

Comment: You mean $f_1^-$ is a typo? Mmm I don't know, that's how it is written in an old prelim exam of analysis.

Comment: It is also not clear if "non-decreasing" is with respect to $x$ (as I assumed in my counter-example above) or with respect to $k$.

Comment: Both: $f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)\leq ....$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: You say "both" but then you only assume non-decreasing in $k$ for all $x$, so I think you really mean "the second one."  So the function $f_1(x)$ can go up and down with $x$, I suppose.

Comment: Am sorry, I meant just in $k$.

Comment: In this case, the problem wants you to use the monotone convergence theorem, but you have to do an appropriate subtraction to make everything non-negative.  The statement about $f_1(x)$ is useful I guess if we assume $f_k(x)\geq f_1(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: In this case, the question makes sense, and $f_1^-(x) = -\min[f_1(x),0]$, as you have guessed.

Comment: How? Could you elaborate?

Comment: You should look at the statement of the monotone convergence theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem  The only reason you cannot _immediately_ apply that theorem is that the $f_k(x)$ functions are not all non-negative. So...

Comment: I know it very well.. I am good with these theorems. But I meant to elaborate on the last two comments of yours.

Comment: Do you see any way to define non-negative functions from the $f_k(x)$ functions, via a simple subtraction?

Comment: No I don't. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try $g_k(x) = f_k(x)-f_1(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is a generalization of Monotone Convergence Theorem :

Consider sequence of functions $g_n(x) = f_n(x)+f_1^-(x)$ (Here $f_1^-$ is understood in the sense $f_1 = f_1^+ - f_1^-$)

Now, observe that sequence $g_n$ is nondecreasing and $g_n \geq 0$ for every $n$. So, from MCT

$$\lim_n\int g_n d\mu = \int \lim_n g_n d\mu $$ which means

$$\lim_n \int f_n d\mu + \int f_1^- d\mu = \int \lim_n f_n d\mu + \int f_1^- d\mu$$

and as $\int f_1^- d\mu < \infty$ we can cancel $\int f_1^- d\mu$ on both sides of the above equality and hence we have the result!

Comment: Perfect and simple! Thanks a lot. But how you were able to notice that? I need your ability in my soon prelim exam.

Comment: Thanks! Solve lots of problems :) Good luck with qual

Comment: Dear Leo, if this was "perfect and simple," what was blocking you from working it out from my hint $g_k(x)=f_k(x)-f_1(x)$ an hour before? You even asked "how were you able to notice that" despite our comment chain on the idea of trying to apply MCT by subtracting something to ensure non-negativity...